# Making a calculator to find the magnitude of a vector on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, vector, jupyter-notebook, tkinter-entry

I've been trying to make a calculator that finds the magnitude of a given 3-dimensional vector using Tkinter on the Jupyter Notebook for my Electromagnetics class.

I've arrived at the following code, which kind of works but it has 3 entry widgets for each of the input coordinates and the numbers entered appear only in the last widget corresponding to the z-coordinate.
The code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Calculator")

coordinates = []

n=0

X = Entry(root)
X.insert(END, "Enter the x-coordinate")
X.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=12, pady=15)

Y = Entry(root)
Y.insert(END, "Enter the y-coordinate")
Y.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=12, pady=15)

Z = Entry(root)
Z.insert(END, "Enter the z-coordinate")
Z.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=12, pady=15)

def x():
    global n
    n=1
    
def y():
    global n
    n=2
    
def z():
    global n
    n=3
    
def S(m):
    if n == 1:
        a = X.get()
        X.delete(0,END)
        X.insert(0,str(a)+str(m))
        coordinates.append(X)
    if n == 2:
        b = Y.get()
        Y.delete(0,END)
        Y.insert(0,str(b)+str(m))
        coordinates.append(Y)
    if n == 3:
        c = Z.get()
        Z.delete(0,END)
        Z.insert(0,str(c)+str(m))
        coordinates.append(Z)
        
def clear():
    X.delete(0,END)
    Y.delete(0,END)
    Z.delete(0,END)
    
def equal():
    sq = 0
    for d in coordinates:
        e = float(d.get())
        sq = sq + e**2 
    mag = sq**0.5
    val = Label(root, text="The magnitude of the vector is: " + str(mag))
    val.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=12, pady=15)
    
b1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("1"))
b2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("2"))
b3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("3"))
b4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("4"))
b5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("5"))
b6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("6"))
b7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("7"))
b8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("8"))
b9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("9"))
b0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=30, pady=15, command=lambda: S("0"))
bx = Button(root, text="x", padx=30, pady=15, command=x())
by = Button(root, text="y", padx=30, pady=15, command=y())
bz = Button(root, text="z", padx=30, pady=15, command=z())
bclear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=19, pady=15, command=clear)
bequal = Button(root, text="=", padx=29, pady=15, command=equal)

b1.grid(row=6, column=0)
b2.grid(row=6, column=1)
b3.grid(row=6, column=2)
b4.grid(row=5, column=0)
b5.grid(row=5, column=1)
b6.grid(row=5, column=2)
b7.grid(row=4, column=0)
b8.grid(row=4, column=1)
b9.grid(row=4, column=2)
b0.grid(row=7, column=1)
bx.grid(row=8, column=0)
by.grid(row=8, column=1)
bz.grid(row=8, column=2)
bclear.grid(row=7, column=2)
bequal.grid(row=7, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Regardless of whether I use the buttons x, y or z, only the third entry widget accepts input. How do I work through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be "calling" the function directly with the `command` of buttons, instead say:

```
bx = Button(root, text="x", padx=30, pady=15, command=x)
by = Button(root, text="y", padx=30, pady=15, command=y)
bz = Button(root, text="z", padx=30, pady=15, command=z)
```

When you use `()` you are calling the function, so to get rid of that, remove the `()`, so the function is called(invoked) only when you press the button.

Comment: That worked! But the calculations still do not seem to be accurate. For instance, when I input 10, 15 and 3 as coordinates it returns 31 as the answer while the actual answer is closer to 18. It does not seem to work when at least one of the inputs is greater than 5!

Comment: @MadCap Dont you think that it is a new Q to be asked, a more mathematical one?

Comment: But i have mentioned in this question as well that the calculations are inaccurate. Won't a new question be flagged as duplicate? @Cool Cloud

Comment: @MadCap Hmmmm, well a question should only focus around one issue, maybe edit this Q to focus around this and ask a new one,

Comment: @MadCap Are you doing the math yourself or are you using any calculators? I tried it on and it quite worked for me, it gave the same output i was expecting, and also, are you sure your not confused how the app works? It took me a whole while to actually figure out how the app is supposed to work. Anyway let me know here when you ask a new Q about this.

Comment: I did use a calculator. Also when I used the app I cleared the default text, selected x, entered the value, then y and so on. Is that not how it works?!

Comment: @MadCap Well for me i had to manually press x button first then remove whats inside the x entry box and then enter the value or press button, then do same for all 3 coordinates and then hit equals, and the answer was correct **only for single digit numbers**. So the problem is how you do the appending and the insert into entry boxes

Comment: That was my problem exactly! I have just posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524111/tkinter-application-returns-random-values